# How to transform snail shells into a fertilizer?

Tags: biochemistry, microbiology, ecology

I heard that the chemical structure of the snail shell has elements that help in waste water treatment and in some cases as a fertilizer?

What is the process used to render snail shells into fertilizer and how effective is the derived fertilizer compared his regular peers on the market ?

Answer (score 2):

Snail shells are composed largely of calcium, which is often used as fertilizer. As for wastewater treatment, I've heard about shells in general being used, mostly for their absorbent properties. I found [this paper](http://sciencepub.net/academia/aa0201/06_0805_treatment_pub_aa0201.pdf), which isn't long & might provide a bit more detail.

Hope that helps!

Comment: May I ask about the quality of the fertilizer derived from the shells and their effectiveness compared to other fertilizers on the market ?